# Как изменить название ключей в объекте?

Tags: javascript

Есть массив, с элементами в виде объекта:

```
const users = [
    { name: 'John', age: 32 },
    { name: 'Mike', age: 25 },
    { name: 'Pieter', age: 27 },
];
```

Как сделать, чтобы функция возращала такой же массив объектов, но ключи объекта должны быть не name/age, а  value и  count:

```
const users = [
    { value: 'John', count: 32 },
    { value: 'Mike', count: 25 },
    { value: 'Pieter', count: 27 },
];
```

Возможно тут reduce может помочь, но я пока не понимаю как именно.

Comment: `map` тут может помочь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это можно сделать через метод [Map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const users = [
    { name: 'John', age: 32 },
    { name: 'Mike', age: 25 },
    { name: 'Pieter', age: 27 },
];

var new_object = users.map(function(obj) {
  return {'value': obj.name, 'count': obj.age};
});
console.log(new_object);
```